# How to control subgraphs' layout in dot?

Tags: graphviz, dot

i have a `digraph` composed of many independant and simple `subgraphs` of various sizes. `dot` lays all these subgraphs horizontally, so i end up with a 40000x200 output file, e.g:

```
G1 G2 G3 G.....4 G5
```

How do i tell `dot` to layout these subgraphs in both dimensions to get something like:

```
G1 G2 G3
G.....4
G5
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The steps to achieve this uses **multiple graphviz tools** which can be piped together.

The following line is a possible configuration, *graph.dot* being the file which contains your graph(s). You may have to fiddle with the options.

```
ccomps -x graph.dot | dot | gvpack -array3 | neato -Tpng -n2 -o graph.png
```

And here's the explanation:

---

### 1. Separate disconnected graphs

Tool: **ccomps**

> decomposes graphs into their connected components

The `-x` option (*Only the connected components are printed, as separate graphs*) is probably all that is needed.

---

### 2. Layout each graph

Tool: **dot**

Each directed graph is layed out, one by one. This step is needed to get the position of the nodes and edges.

---

### 3. Pack all layed out graphs into one

Tool: **gvpack**

> reads in a stream of graphs, combines the graphs into a single layout,
>   and produces a single graph serving as the union of the input graphs.

You should read the documentation of the options for this tool and play with the options. For example, `-array` is used to lay out the graphs in a grid like manner, and offers several flags to control the layout.

---

### 4. Create the output

Tool: **neato**

The option `-n2` tells neato to not layout the input graphs but to use the existing position attributes.

---

Example graph:

[image: graphiz gvpack]

```
digraph G {
 subgraph G1 {
    a->{b; c;};
 }
 subgraph G2 {
    d -> {e; f;};
 }
 subgraph G3 {
    g -> h;
 }
 subgraph G4 {
    i -> j;
 }
 subgraph G5 {
    {k; l;} -> m;
 }
}
```

---

**Edit:** Sorting the digraphs in gvpack

In order to determine the order of appearance od the subgraphs in the combined layout created by `gvpack`, each subgraph will need a `sortv` attribute.

For example, the following graphs:

```
digraph G1 {
 sortv=1;
 a->{b; c;};
}
digraph G2 {
 sortv=2;
 d -> {e; f;};
}
digraph G3 {
 sortv=3;
 g -> h;
}
digraph G4 {
 sortv=4;
 i -> j;
}
digraph G5 {
 sortv=5;
 {k; l;} -> m;
}
```

can be transformed using

```
dot graph.dot | gvpack -array_u | neato -Tpng -n2 -o graph.png
```

resulting in

[image: packed graph with ordered subgraphs]

Comment: Thanks. ccomps actually just rewrite my subgraphs into digraphs. The real work is done by gvpack.

Comment: Is there a way to sort the digraphs then ?

Comment: Yes, `ccomps` separates disconnected graphs. If you don't need this, you max create separate graphs from the start. You may add a `sortv` attribute to each (sub-)graph. _The
"u" flag indicates that the insertion order is based on the sortv attribute attached to each graph._ -  therefore, using `gvpack -array_u3` should order the appearance of the graphs by the value of their `sortv` attribute.