# Graphviz nodes rendering

Tags: graphviz

I have a simple graphviz graph that is drawn as shown in the following image:

```
digraph G {
        "Model" -> "Task";
        "Task" -> "Worker 1" -> "Sink";
        "Task" -> "Worker 2" -> "Sink";
        "Task" -> "Worker 3" -> "Sink";
}
```

[image]

Adding and edge between the sink and task nodes, the graph output is shown the following image:

```
    "Sink" -> "Model";
```

[image]

How could I add this edge and keep the original symmetric node layout shown in the first image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Edited to improve my original answer)

Building on the answer to [How to control subgraphs' layout in dot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002352/how-to-control-subgraphs-layout-in-dot), if we start by laying out the core digraph with `dot`, we can then use `neato` to add the additional edge. `neato` allows nodes that already have defined positions to be pinned using the `-n` parameter so one could do something like this (where `symmetric.dot` contains the original GraphViz digraph with the addition of `graph [splines = true]`):

```
#!/bin/bash
dot -Tdot symmetric.dot >symmetric1.dot
neato -n2 -Tpng symmetric1.dot -osymmetric1.png
sed 's/^}/"Sink" -> "Model";}/' <symmetric1.dot  >symmetric2.dot
neato -n2 -Tdot symmetric2.dot >symmetric3.dot
neato -n2 -Tpng symmetric3.dot -osymmetric3.png
```

This script:

1. Uses `dot` to lay out the original digraph into a new `.dot` file.
2. Uses `neato -n2` to plot the original digraph. The `-n2` option prevents `neato` from moving nodes that already have positions.
3. Uses `sed` to insert the `"Sink" -> "Model"` edge.
4. Uses `neato -n2` to lay out the new edge (which is the only one without `pos` defined, and thus the only one not pinned) and plot it as a `.png` file.

`symmetric1.png` looks like this:

[image]

... and `symmetric3.dot` with the additional edge looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I would like to have a directed graph structure but it looks like this is not possible with `neato`

Comment: @MigueldeVal-Borro I've updated my answer to use `dot` first and referenced another question and answer where the answer shows that we don't have to use `neato` for the first step.